# Invalid use of Property Error: For each row in Table, apply to only the cells of the first column

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I modify the following to loop over the first column of a table in word rather than applying it to all cells of a table?

Additionally, how can I have this iterate over every table within the document?

```
Sub AddToEveryCell()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rw As Row
    Dim cl As Cell
    
    
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                cl.Range.Text = _
                    Left(cl.Range.Text, Len(cl.Range.Text) - 2) _
                    & "|"  ' <= the character you want to add
            Next cl
        Next rw
    Else
        MsgBox "Put the cursor in the table and rerun this macro."
    End If
End Sub
```

Attempt I have explored is:

```
Dim tbl As Table
Dim rw As Row
Dim cl As Cell

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        cl = rw.Cells(1) ' only loop through the first column
            cl.Range.Text = _
                Left(cl.Range.Text, Len(cl.Range.Text) - 2) _
                & "|"  ' <= the character you want to add
    Next rw
Else
    MsgBox "Put the cursor in the table and rerun this macro."
End If
```

However, I am getting an invalid use of property error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the second of your attempts and initially got the same error as you. Then I added a "Set" before  cl = rw.Cells(1), I had a vague memory of having this problem before... then it worked just fine.
Objects and variables needs to be assigned using set, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement

I pasted the macro that worked on my computer below.

```
Sub q2()
'
Dim tbl As Table
Dim rw As Row
Dim cl As Cell

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        Set cl = rw.Cells(1) ' only loop through the first column
        Debug.Print "in for"
            cl.Range.Text = _
                Left(cl.Range.Text, Len(cl.Range.Text) - 2) _
                & "|"  ' <= the character you want to add
    Next rw
Else
    MsgBox "Put the cursor in the table and rerun this macro."
End If
'
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, don't think i would have worked it out. Even GPT3 couldn't fix it ahah

Answer (score 1):

Try the following if statement :

```
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables ' loop through all tables in the document
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                cl = rw.Cells(1) ' only loop through the first column
                cl.Range.Text = _
                    Left(cl.Range.Text, Len(cl.Range.Text) - 2) _
                    & "|"  ' <= the character you want to add
            Next rw
        Next tbl
    Else
        MsgBox "Put the cursor in the table and rerun this macro."
    End If
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I'm still getting the invalid use of property error. USeful though as it seems that the code is probably fine and im missing some... reference? unsure.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to process the first column you should loop through the cells of that column, rather than looping through the rows. To apply the code to all the tables in the document is as simple as looping through the tables.

```
Sub AddToFirstColCells()

    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim cl As Cell

    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each cl In tbl.Columns(1).Cells
            cl.Range.Text = _
                Left(cl.Range.Text, Len(cl.Range.Text) - 2) _
                & "|"  ' <= the character you want to add
        Next cl
    Next tbl
End Sub
```